Curl http request time out
In http request it working fine (local environment), but when I change to cloudflare Full (strict), it return error of time out. I try to add my ssl certificate config, but still not working!
nginx/Site-enabled
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;


POST request
      public function applyFabricToken()
      {
        $ch = curl_init();
  
        $headers = array(
          "Content-Type: application/json",
          "X-APP-Key: " . $this->fabricAppId
        );
  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->BASE_URL . "/payment/v1/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  
        $payload =  array(
          "appSecret" => $this->appSecret
        );
  
        //print_r(json_encode($payload));exit;
        $data = json_encode($payload);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);// for dev env
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); // for dev environment only
        // Enable SSL verification for production
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/path/to/your/client_cert.pem'); 
       //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '/path/to/your/client_key.pem'); 

  
  
        // Timeout in seconds
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  
        $authToken = curl_exec($ch);
  
        return $authToken;
      }

Error Timeout

what exact error you are getting beside timeout? Show us the cURL error.
`if ($authToken === false) {
$error = curl_error($ch);
$errno = curl_errno($ch);
}`

Do this and let us know what does it shows in the logs?

Is it OPERATION_TIMEOUTED?

$error =string(45) "Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds" $errno= int(28)

I think its receiver endpoint problem (they need to whitelist my ip), Idk

Add this curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/your/ssl/cacert.pem'); ,Most likely it will solve your issue

client end point is like this https://196.188.120.3:38443/apiaccess/payment/../payment/v1/token its not using the common 443 ssl port no, I am guessing they are using proxy something, any one have any idea?
